# Adding tab keypress to fields in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've got a customer form with about 15 fields. When I tab from field to field I need an event to capture this, check if there are at least 3 fields or the 15 with data entered and then use that data to go off to a web service and do some stuff.

How do I do it?

Comment: you could use directive and do watch on `ng-model` value, if its valid then do `$http` call

Comment: @pankajparkar can I apply a watch to a group of ng-model properties?

Comment: yes you can, depend on which angular version you are using. It would be `$watchGroup` or `$watchCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example using $watchCollection:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.input = {};
  
  $scope.$watchCollection('input', function(n) {
    if (Object.keys(n).length > 2) {
      $scope.disabled = true;
      alert('tada!')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
  <div>a<input ng-model="input.a" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-disabled="disabled"></div>
  <div>b<input ng-model="input.b" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-disabled="disabled"></div>
  <div>c<input ng-model="input.c" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-disabled="disabled"></div>
  <div>d<input ng-model="input.d" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" ng-disabled="disabled"></div>
  <div> {{ input }} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are need only to identify the tab key press, then you can use,

```
ng-blur
```

directive.

```
<input type='text' ng-blur="test()" />
```

in test function you can check, whether user pressed tab key event or not. or you can use `ng-keyup directive`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking advantage of ngModel and form validation.

### Usage

1. Use the `minimumFields` directive to specify the minimum number of fields needed to pass validation.
2. For each field with an ngModel that you want to include for validation, add a `field` directive.
3. Bind to the validation error `minimumFields` using ngMessages
4. In the submit handler check that the form is valid before submitting.

### Example

```
  <form name='myform'>
    Error Object: {{myform.$error }}
    <div minimum-fields="3">
      Field1 <input type="text" field name="field1" ng-model="field1" /></br> 
      Field2 <input type="text" field name="field2" ng-model="field2" /></br>
      Field3 <input type="text" field name="field3" ng-model="field3" /></br>
      Field4 <input type="text" field name="field4" ng-model="field4" /></br>
      Field5 <input type="text" field name="field5" ng-model="field5" /></br>
      Field6 <input type="text" field name="field6" ng-model="field6" /></br>
      Field7 <input type="text" field name="field7" ng-model="field7" /></br>
      Field8 <input type="text" field name="field8" ng-model="field8" /></br>
      Field9 <input type="text" field name="field9" ng-model="field9" /></br>
    </div>

    <div ng-messages="myform.$error">
       <span ng-message="minimumFields">A minimum of 3 fields must be populated</span>
    </div>
     <button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

### Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('app' ,['ngMessages']);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.myform.$valid) {
      alert('submitted!');
    }
  }
});
app.directive('minimumFields', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.fields = [];
      this.register = function(field) {       
        $scope.fields.push(field);
        
      }
    },
    link: function(scope, element,attr, formController) {
      var fieldCount = parseInt(attr.minimumFields);
      scope.$watch(function() {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach(scope.fields, function(field) {
          if (field.$viewValue != undefined && field.$viewValue != '') {
            ++count;
          }
        });
        return count < fieldCount;
      }, function(newVal) {
          
          formController.$setValidity('minimumFields', !newVal);    
     
      });
                        
      
    }
  }
});

app.directive('field', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    require: ['^minimumFields','ngModel'],
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
      var minimumFieldsCtrl = ctrls[0];
      var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[1];
      minimumFieldsCtrl.register(ngModelCtrl);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-messages.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name='myform'>
    Error Object: {{myform.$error }}
    <div minimum-fields="3">
      Field1 <input type="text" field name="field1" ng-model="field1" /></br> 
      Field2 <input type="text" field name="field2" ng-model="field2" /></br>
      Field3 <input type="text" field name="field3" ng-model="field3" /></br>
      Field4 <input type="text" field name="field4" ng-model="field4" /></br>
      Field5 <input type="text" field name="field5" ng-model="field5" /></br>
      Field6 <input type="text" field name="field6" ng-model="field6" /></br>

    </div>
   
    <div ng-messages="myform.$error">
       <span ng-message="minimumFields">A minimum of 3 fields must be populated</span>
    </div>
     <button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```